# prove that $\,5\,$ is factor of $\,\,3^{2n+1}+ 2^{2n+1}$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Actually I have done this problem by induction.(trivial)
Please tell me another method to do this problem instead of induction.

Comment: Modular arithmetic. Hands-on version: binomial expansion on $(5-2)^{2n+1}$.

Comment: See "Why is $a^n−b^n$ divisible by $a−b$?": $\ $http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

*Note:* This solution assumes that the edit made by user Souvik Dey is in line with the OP's intent.

Note that $$
3^{2n+1}=3\cdot 9^n\equiv 3\cdot(-1)^n\pmod{5}
$$
and
$$
2^{2n+1}=2\cdot 4^n\equiv 2\cdot(-1)^n\pmod{5}.
$$
So, we have
$$
3^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}\equiv 5\cdot(-1)^n\equiv0\pmod{5}.
$$

Comment: $$3^{3n}\not\equiv9^n\pmod{5}$$

Comment: >tfw $3\times 3\times 3=9$

Comment: Hah, woops.  True story.

Comment: There, fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

As for integer $a,b$ and integer $n\ge0,$
  $a^n-b^n$ is divisible by $(a-b)$( Proof [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430645/prove-that-a-b-mid-an-bn),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b))

$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=a^{2n+1}-(-b)^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $a-(-b)=a+b$

Comment: Wish I know, why does the downvote  persist now?

Comment: Can't say; this is a legit answer. Geo sum formula is more low-tech than modular arithmetic and slicker than binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=3^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}$.

- $3=-2\pmod{5}$ hence $A=(-2)^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}\pmod{5}$
- $(-2)^{2n+1}=-2^{2n+1}$ hence $A=0\pmod{5}$

Likewise, $3^{2n}+2^{2n}=(-2)^{2n}+2^{2n}=2\cdot2^{2n}$ hence $5$ does not divide $3^k+2^k$ when $k$ is even, only when $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

By induction: For $n=0$ the result is clear.

Suppose the result true for $n$.
$$3^{2(n+1)+1}+2^{2(n+1)+1}=9.3^{2n+1}+4.2^{2n+1}=4\left(3^{2n+1}+2^{2n+1}\right)+5.3^{2n+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$3\equiv-2\mod5,$$ we have $$3^{2n+1}\equiv(-2)^{2n+1}\equiv-2^{2n+1}\mod5,$$
and therefore
$$2^{2n+1}+3^{2n+1}\equiv2^{2n+1}(1-1)\equiv0\mod5$$

Comment: Oh, I see Did posted the same solution while I was composing this one.  We differ only in presentation (and Did's additional remark).