# Prove by induction that $a-b|a^n-b^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, induction, divisibility

Given $a,b,n \in \mathbb N$, prove that $a-b|a^n-b^n$. I think about induction. The assertion is obviously true for $n=1$. If I assume that assertive is true for a given $k \in \mathbb N$, i.e.: $a-b|a^k-b^k$, I should be able to find that $a-b|a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}$, but I can't do it. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: Rankeya's [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/188702/8271) addresses  what is asked here.

Comment: The assertion is even moreobviously true for $n=0$, by the way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complete the induction, note that

$a^{k + 1} - b^{k + 1} = a^{k + 1} - a^kb + a^kb - b^{k + 1} = a^k(a - b) + b(a^k - b^k), \tag{1}$

then simply observe that

$(a - b) \mid a^k(a - b), \tag{2}$

which is obvious, and that

$(a - b) \mid (a^k -b^k) \tag{3}$

by the induction hypothesis

$(a - b) \mid (a^k - b^k). \tag{4}$

Since $a - b$ divides both summands, it divides their sum.***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you very much, Robert!

Comment: @ Walter:  my pleasure, glad to be of service.  And thanks for your "acceptance"!  I'm sorry to see your question was closed (not my doing, by the way), but I guess it has been asked before on MSE.  Best Regards, Robert Kenneth Lewis