# Problem on multiplication formulae.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given $a^3 + b^{3}+ c^{3}= (a+b+c)^{3} $.

Prove that for any natural number $n$,
$$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=(a+b+c)^{2n+1}$$

I first tried mathematical induction but did not proceed anywhere.
Can the formula $(a+b+c)^{3}=a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$   be directly used?
Can this problem be solved using mathematical induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**
Using Induction

We have $$(a+b+c)^{3}=a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\implies(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$$

Now, for $k$ we have

$$(a+b+c)^{2k+1}=a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1}$$
For $(k+1)$
$$(a+b+c)^{2k+3}=(a+b+c)^2(a+b+c)^{2k+1}=(a+b+c)^2(a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}+c^{2k+1})$$

$$(a+b+c)^{2k+3}=a^{2k+3}+b^{2k+3}+c^{2k+3}+(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)(\text{some factor})$$

(I've left the job of finding factor to you for observing pattern see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E2*%28a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%29+-a%5E5-b%5E5-c%5E5) and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+%28a%2Bb%2Bc%29%5E2*%28a%5E5%2Bb%5E5%2Bc%5E5%29+-a%5E7-b%5E7-c%5E7))

Using $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$
$$(a+b+c)^{2k+3}=a^{2k+3}+b^{2k+3}+c^{2k+3}$$

**Solution 2**

$$(a+b+c)^{3}=a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+3(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\implies(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=0$$
Either of $a+b,b+c,c+a =0$

$\implies (a+b+c)=a$ or $(a+b+c)=b$ or $(a+b+c)=c$

In any case $$(a+b+c)^{2n+1}=a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you think an Inductive argument will work?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)^3-a^3$$

$$\iff(b+c)(b^2-bc+c^2)=(a+b+c-a)\{(a+b+c)^2+a(a+b+c)+a^2\}$$

$$\iff(b+c)\{3a^2+3ab+3bc+3ca\}=0$$

$$\iff(b+c)(a+b)(a+c)=0$$

As the product of three terms is zero, hence at least one of them must be zero

If $b+c=0, a+b+c=a\implies (a+b+c)^{2n+1}=?$

and using [Prove by induction that $a-b|a^n-b^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580788/prove-by-induction-that-a-ban-bn),

$b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=b^{2n+1}-(-c)^{2n+1}$ is diviisble by $b-(-c)=b+c$

$\implies b+c=0\implies b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=0\implies a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=? $

Similarly, if $c+a=0$ or if $a+b=0$

Comment: Thank you. Nice tweak in your answer. Brilliantly done.