# How to prove that $8^{18} - 1$ is divisible by $7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

How to prove that: $$ 8^{18}-1\equiv0\pmod7 $$
In the simplest way?

Comment: Use  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yet another one: $a^{18}-b^{18}=(a-b)\left(a^{17}+a^{16}b+\cdots+ab^{16}+b^{17}\right) \ ,$ hence $$8^{18}-1=(8-1)\left(8^{17}+8^{16}+\cdots+8+1\right),\quad\text{which is a multiple of $7$.}$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** $$ 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7\ \  \text{and}\ \  a^n \equiv b^n \mod m$$ Given any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, \ \ m > 1$ and $n \geq 1$ such that $a \equiv b \mod m$.

Comment: You mean: given any $a$ and $b$ *such that $a\equiv b\mod m$*.

Comment: That's right, I typed fast.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found overall formula:
$$ a^n \equiv b^n \pmod {a-b} $$
hence:
$$ 8^{18} \equiv 1^{18} \pmod {8-1} $$

$$ 8^{18} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {8-1} $$

Comment: Which is a way of **not** solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just note that $8^{18}-1=7\cdot2573485501354569$.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comment?

Comment: @DigitalBrain I believe that this really answers the question.