# Using induction for $x^n - 1$ is divisible by $x - 1$

Tags: polynomials, induction

Prove using induction that for all non-negative integers n and for all integers $ x > 1 $, $ x^n - 1 $ is divisible by $ x - 1 $.

Step 1: We will prove this using induction on n.
Step 2: Assume the claim is true when $ n = 1 $.
$$ x^{n+1} - 1 = x(x^n - 1) + (x - 1) $$

Can someone help me with this further?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: The sum of two terms that are divisible by $x-1$ is also divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: If $x^n-1$ is divisible by $x-1$ you can get common factor.

Comment: Your step 2 should say "Assume the claim is true for some positive integer n; we'll show it's true for $n + 1$." And before it should be Step 1.5: "We'll first show the claim is true for $n = 1$", with an explanation. To continue the general case proof, what can you say about the $x^n -1$ on the right hand side? What degree is it?

Comment: you've done it, since $x-1$ divides $x-1$, obviously, and $x-1$ divides $x^n-1$ by the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: You don't *assume* it's true for $n=1$, you show it. So what do you get for $n=1$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$x^{n+1} - 1 = x(x^n - 1) + (x - 1)=x(x-1)(?) + (x - 1)=(x-1)(x(?) + 1)$$

**Alternative**: Actually We don't need to use Induction,

Let $f(x)=x^n-1$
Now $f(1)=0$, That means $1$ is a root if $f(x)$ so $f(x)=(x-1)\times(?)$ ( By '$?$' I mean some another factors as $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree $n$ )

Comment: Are the question makes equal to x or to the power of n?