# The residue of $x^{15}-1$ divided by $x^2-1$

Tags: linear-algebra

The residue of $x^{15}-1$ divided by $x^2-1$

---

I want to use the long division, but I don't know how to start

Comment: Hint: $\;x^2-1\;$ has two rather easy roots, one, and only one, of which is also a root of $\;x^{15}-1\;$ .

Comment: $$x((x^2)^7-1^7)+x-1$$

Now use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: We want the remainder when $P(x)=x^{14}+\cdots+1$ is divided by $x+1$. Let $P(x)=(x+1)Q(x)+r$. Set $x=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Observe that $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$;

$x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$,

$\dots$

Generally, $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots+x^2+x+1)$