# The solutions to $x^m \equiv 1 \bmod p$ will all be solutions to $x^{mn} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for any $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can you please show the proof of

"The solutions to $x^m \equiv 1 \bmod p$ will all be solutions to $x^{mn} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for any $n$."

Comment: If $x^m\equiv 1$ mod $p$, then $x^{mn} \equiv 1^n \equiv 1$ mod $p$.

Comment: $$x^{mn}=(x^m)^n$$  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: I have asked the question to clarify if  $p\nmid(2^a-1)$ that $p\nmid 2^{ab}-1$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Do you know the proof of $$x \equiv a \mod m \implies x^n \equiv a^n \mod m$$

For any integer $n>0$ and given $x,a,m$? If not, try to prove this by induction first.

Comment: $x^n-a^n=(x-a)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}a+\cdots+a^{n-1})$ proves it.