# Proof that $2^{2n}-1$ is not prime for $n \in \mathbb{N}, n > 1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, induction

I notice that the number seems to be a multiple of 3:

for n=2: $2^4 -1 = 15 $

for n=3: $2^6 -1 = 63$

for n=4: $2^8 -1 = 255$

How do I generalise?

Comment: It is quite difficult for a difference of squares to be a prime number. $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$

Comment: I feel really stupid now. Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b)

Comment: This may be a specific case of a broader question, so to call it a duplicate is misleading, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

we have $$2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$

Answer (score 3):

$2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$, so it's always composite (unless $n=1$, in which case we have $3=(1)(3)$).

In addition, it's always a multiple of $3$, for the following reason. Since $2^n$ is never a multiple of $3$, it's either one more or one less than a multiple of $3$. This means that one of $2^n-1$ and $2^n+1$ is a multiple of $3$. Thus, $2^{2n}-1=(2^n-1)(2^n+1)$ is a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{2n}-1$ is always divisible for $3$. Indeed $$2^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

If you have studied the $3x + 1$ problem even briefly, you know that the powers of 2 alternate between $-1$ and $1 \pmod 3$: $$2 = 3 - 1$$ $$4 = 3 + 1$$ $$8 = 9 - 1$$ $$16 = 15 + 1$$ $$32 = 33 - 1$$ This means that $2^{2n + 1} \equiv -1 \pmod 3$ and $2^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. From this you just make a tiny hop to arrive at the conclusion that $2^{2n} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. The only positive multiple of 3 that is prime is 3 itself. Therefore all $n > 1$ give composite multiples of 3.