# Find the last digit of $66^5$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find the last digit of $66^5$.

This is how I solved the problem: $66^5=6^5*11^5$ (mod 10) = $6^5*1^5$ (mod 10). I have two questions. First, what is wrong with my method? I get different answer from answer sheet. Second, is there an easy way to find the last digit of $6^5$?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ By induction $\ a^2\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, a^n \equiv a\ $ for all $\,n \ge 1\ \ $

Comment: **Or:** $\ 6^n\equiv 0\pmod 2\,$ and $\,6^n \equiv 1^n\equiv\color{#c00} 1\pmod{5}\,$ so $\,6^n \equiv \color{#c00}1+5\pmod{10}\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

Observe that $6^n \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$, where $n$ is a positive integer.

---

With this hint, it may be seen that nothing is wrong with your answer as

> $66^5 =6^5 \cdot 11^5 \equiv 6^5 \cdot 1 \equiv 6 \pmod {10}$

Comment: @learning Yes, $6^2=36 \equiv 6\pmod {10}$

Answer (score 2):

For integer $n\ge0,$ $$6^{n+1}-6=6(6^n-1^n)\equiv0\pmod{10}$$  using [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b/188710)