# does $x-y$ divide $x^{2k-1}-y^{2k-1}$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory

I noticed this trend in Wolfram Alpha for that $x-y$ divides $x^3-y^3, x^5-y^5, x^7-y^7$ so I was wondring if it is true for all $ k \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Does remainder theorem ring a bell? What happens if you substitute $x=y$ in any of the higher order expressions? This is one way to look at it...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b/188710

Comment: Out of curiosity: why only the odd powers? It holds for even powers too.

Comment: @SteamyRoot even was trivial for me

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks I understand now

Comment: @imranfat ah, I get it now, slightly embarrassed at the moment

Answer (score 3):

In general, $x^{2k+1}-y^{2k+1} = (x-y)(x^{2k} + x^{2k-1} y + \dots + x y^{2k-1} + y^{2k})$.

$$ x(x^{2k} + x^{2k-1} y + \dots + x y^{2k-1} + y^{2k}) = x^{2k+1} + x^{2k} y + \dots + x^2 y^{2k-1} + x y^{2k} $$

$$ y(x^{2k} + x^{2k-1} y + \dots + x y^{2k-1} + y^{2k}) = \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;x^{2k}y + x^{2k-1} y^2 + \dots + x y^{2k} + y^{2k+1}$$

so subtracting the two lines proves the desired result.