# Prove by induction divisibility by 9,.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

Stuck toward the end of the proof:

> Prove: That $5\cdot10^n + 10^{n-1} + 3$ is divisible by $9$:

If $n=1$ then $5\cdot10^1 + 10^{1-1} + 3= 5\cdot10+10^0+3=54
 $

$9$ surely divides $54$.

Assume, If $k$ is a natural number such that $9/5\cdot10^k + 10^{k-1} + 3$

then show that 
$$9/5\cdot10^{k+1}+5\cdot10^k + 3$$
$$9/10\cdot(5\cdot 10^{k+1}+5\cdot10^k + 3)$$
$$9/5\cdot10^{k+2}+5\cdot10^{k+1} + 10\cdot3$$

Stuck here I need to get each term to be divisible by $9$. I am stuck trying to get this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Users take the time to give you something properly formatted; you should do the same.

Comment: $$5(10^n-1)+(10^{n-1}-1)+9$$  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b/188710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference
\begin{align*}
5\cdot 10^{k+1} +10^k + 3 - (5\cdot 10^{k} +10^{k-1} + 3) &= 5\cdot 10^k(10-1) + 10^{k-1}(10-1) \\
&= 9(5\cdot 10^k + 10^{k-1})
\end{align*}
is a multiple of 9. 
Since by inductive assumption, $5\cdot 10^{k} +10^{k-1} + 3$ is a multiple of 9, it follows that $5\cdot 10^{k+1} +10^k + 3 $ is also a multiple of 9.

Comment: Aside from subtraction, is there anyway I can manipulate what I wrote out to get something similar to your final statement.

Comment: You can expand $10^{k+1}$ and $10^{k+2}$ using binomial theorem expressing them as $(9+1)^{k+1}$ and $(9+1)^{k+2}$. This will give the result directly (without induction).

Comment: how did you get $$51*10^{n-1}$$

Comment: $5 \cdot 10^{n} + 10^{n-1} = 5 \cdot 10 \cdot 10^{n-1} + 10^{n-1} = 51 \cdot 10^{n-1}$

Comment: So in my original proof when I multiplied by 10 I did not have to multiply the other side by 10? I found a similar proof that does so and it has thrown me off