# Prove That $6^n -1$ is composite

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Prove That $6^n -1$ is composite $\forall n>1 \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: What is the "unit digit" of any such $6^{n}$? What is it once you subtract the 1? What can you say about all numbers with such last digit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use $$(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1}).$$

Another method would be to see that $6 \equiv 1 (\mod 5)$ and $6^n \equiv1^n(\mod 5) \equiv 1(\mod 5)$. Now subtract 1 and see what happens.