# Irreducibility of $X^n-p^m$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to show the following:

Let $p$ be a prime numer and $n,m \geq 1$ prime. $$f(X):=X^n-p^m$$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. Also, this statement is generally wrong, if $m, n$ aren't prime.

I tried to use the Eisenstein-criteria, but I don't think it works here (or at least it didn't work out, when I tried). For the last part I thought about simply showing a counter-example, but I can't think of a proper one...

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: The claim is false if $n=m$.

Comment: @N.S. But then $n$ and $m$ are not coprime. (I suppose the OP means "if $m,n$ aren't coprime").

Comment: @DietrichBurde The problem says prime, not co-prime.

Comment: @N.S. I kinda overlooked that possibility... Thank you.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hmm... I don't see the other problem being similar to mine. If the other post has anything to do with Galois-Theory, I'm afraid, I haven't learned anything about that yet. If there is any other connection between the two posts, would you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: You can apply Bill's answer for $c=p^m$, and also look into the book he has cited. For the counterexample you can use [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b). And your sentence "*Also, this statement is generally wrong, if m,n aren't prime*" is not correct.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry, but I don't understand most of the notations in the book he recommends and I can't really follow the steps. Would you mind explaining it to me shortly?

Comment: This is actually more of an duplicate of this question: [Irreducibility of $f(x)=x^n-p^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737930/irreducibility-of-fx-xn-pm/2768318#2768318) .