# $p^{n-1}x^n - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ for $p$ prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Consider $f(x) = p^{n-1}x^n - 1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. I want to show that it's irreducible when $p$ is prime.

Neither reduction of the coefficients modulo some prime nor Eisenstein seems to work here.

I also have had no luck finding a suitable substitution (such as $f(x+1)$) to apply  one of these tests to. I may be miscalculating something, but I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you substitute $x$ for $x/p$, and then you multiply by $p$ in order not to have denominators, then you get the polynomial $x^n-p$. But then [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) for the prime $p$ gives you the irreducibility.

Comment: Generally $$\begin{align} &\,p(p^{n-1}x^n + a_{n-1}(px)^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1(p x) + a_0)\\[.2em] =\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ X^n\ +\ pa_{n-1} X^n\ +\cdots\ +\ pa_1 X + pa_0\end{align}$$ is Eisenstein if $\,p\nmid a_0\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

Warning: This method is quite overkill, see xarles' answer for simple method.

You can consider reverted polynomial $x^nf(1/x)=-x^n+p^{n-1}$. This polynomial will be irreducible iff the original polynomial is irreducible (see [Prove that the polynomial $x^nf(1/x)$ with reverted coefficients is also irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963477/prove-that-the-polynomial-xnf1-x-with-reverted-coefficients-is-also-irreduc) ). To show this final polynomial is irreducible, [Newton polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polygon) can be used (see [Explaining Newton Polygon for proving irreducibility of polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in elementary way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671738/explaining-newton-polygon-for-proving-irreducibility-of-polynomial-in-mathbbz)).

Basically if you construct Newton polygon corresponding to $p$, you will get line segment between $[0,n-1]$ and $[n,0]$. Since this line does not pass through any other integer points in between (because $\gcd(n,n-1)=1$), then by Dumas' theorem the polynomial is irreducible.

For more information about these (and another) tools related to polynomial irreducibility, see this answer [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions/28876#28876). Also the polynomial with reverted coefficients is special case of this one: [Irreducibility of $f(x)=x^n-p^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737930/irreducibility-of-fx-xn-pm/2768318#2768318) .

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I suggest you find the complex roots (not so hard), i.e., factorize the polynomial into a product of unary complex polynomials. 
Then show that it is impossible to partition these unary factors into two nonempty sets so that the product of each is a rational polynomial.

Focus on the constant term!