# Is $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a+b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Is $a^n+b^n$ is divisible by $a+b$ ?

This question arose when I found this post [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b) in these pages.

I addressed the question as follows:

$$
a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2 -a^{n-4}b^3+\cdots\pm b^{n-1})\\
\begin{align}
=a^n &-a^{n-1}b-a^{n-2}b^2+a^{n-3}b^3 -a^{n-4}b^4+\cdots\pm ab^{n-1})\\
&+a^{n-1}b+a^{n-2}b^2-a^{n-3}b^3 +a^{n-4}b^4-\cdots\mp ab^{n-1}\pm b^n)\\
=a^n\pm b^n
\end{align}
$$

where the +sign applies to odd $n$ and the -sign to even $n$. Therefore we find that

$$
a+b|a^n+b^n,\quad n \text{ odd}\\
a+b|a^n-b^n,\quad n \text{ even}
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: `a^n+b^n = (a-b)(...)` The identity is wrong as written. Try it for $n=2$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv That was a typo. Thanks for you keen eye; I have corrected it.

Comment: It seems right to me.

Comment: The identity is still wrong. Again, try it for $n=2\,$: $\;a^2+b^2=(a+b) \,\cdot\, (\,?\,)\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Sorry, in your example $n$ is even, so $\;a^2-b^2=(a+b) (a-b)$.

Comment: Well, in the case $n$ even, you can say more:
$$a^2-b^2|a^n-b^n$$

Comment: @CyeWaldman Sorry, but you essentially wrote $\,a^n+b^n=\;\cdots\;=a^n \pm b^n\,$. I don't follow that.

Comment: @dxiv Quite correct, that cannot be true; that's why I had to split it into two results. One for each sign, in order to make it so. In other words, I started out with the assertion $a^2+b^2=\cdots$, but found out that it was something else when $n$ is even.

Comment: If $a,b,n$ are positive integers and $n$ is even then $(a+b)|(a^n+b^n)$ iff 
 $a=b=2^m$ for some integer $m\geq 0.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Well, then why not $(a+b)|(a^n+b^n)$ iff $a=b$?

Comment: Right. That's what I get for trying to do it all in my head.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That's okay, you prompted me to see something i had not seen before, even though it's a degenerate case. So, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It is if $n$ is odd. This is a high school identity:

$$a^{2p+1}+b^{2p+1}=(a+b)\bigl(a^{2p}-a^{2p-1}b+a^{2p-2}b^2-\dots-ab^{2p-1}+b^{2p}\bigr)$$