# Prove using Mathematical Induction that $2^{3n}-3^n$ is divisible by $5$ for all $n≥1$.

Tags: induction

I did most of it but I stuck here I attached my working 
tell me if I did correct or not thanks

My working:
[image: My working]

EDITED: I wrote the notes as TEX
Prove using induction that $2^{3n} - 3^n \mod{5} = 0$.

Statement is true for $n = 1$: 
$$2^{3 * 1} - 3^1 = 2^3 - 3 = 8 - 3 = 5$$
$$5 \mod{5} = 0$$

Now for $n = p$ and $n = p + 1$:
$$2^{3(k+1)} - 3{k + 1} = 2 * 2^p - 3$$
$$=2(5n + 3) - 3=10n + 6 - 3 = 10n+3$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions. For the rest, please use punctuation and proofread your writing. Where is your work so far?

Comment: Where is your work?

Comment: Also remember to show the statement is _not_ true for $n \leq 1$

Comment: Um... $2^{3*1} = 8$.  Not $18$.

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie  Is that a joke?

Comment: Note that there's a difference between $2^3n-3^n$ and $2^{3n}-3^n$. The former is not always divisible by $5$.

Comment: ... because 1) $n$ is presumed to be a natural number so $n\ge 1$ is a assumed and 2) to proof something is true for CONDITION does *NOT* mean it is false if the condition is not true.

Comment: @fleablood Slightly, but it's true though. Even though we all know that for $n = 0$ $2^{3n} - 3^n = 0$ and that if $n < 0$ then $0 < r < 5$, it should be written down (I guess. I would've noted it at least).

Comment: @SuperSjoerdie It's true for $n=0$, and for $n<0$ the expression is not even an integer, so it doesn't make sense to ask the question of divisibility by $5$.

Comment: It's not relevent.  To prove whales dance when the moon is full, you are under no obigation to prove whales do not dance when the moon is not full and the statement could still be true even if whales do dance when the moon is not full because our statement has nothing to do with non-full moons.

Comment: @fleablood Ah, now I see :') You're right, he doesn't have to

Comment: In step three, your first line is what you need to prove., which is confusing. Your work after that doesn't make sense. Also, your handwriting is rather inconsistent.

Comment: @johnWatson I have put a photo of my work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $a^n - b^n$ is divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-an-bn-is-divisible-by-a-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first show for the $n=1$ case:

$2^3-3 = 8-3 = 5$

which is clearly divisible by 5. Next is the inductive step where we assume

$2^{3n} - 3^n=5m $ for some integer $m$.

We can rewrite this as

$2^{3n}=5m+3^n$.

Now we want to prove that $2^{3(n+1)}-3^{n+1}$ is divisible by 5. We first can simplify this a bit:

$2^{3(n+1)}-3^{n+1} = 2^{3n+3}-3^{n+1}=2^3\cdot2^{3n}-3\cdot 3^n$.

We can now make the substitution from the previous statement to write this as

$2^3(5m+3^n)-3\cdot 3^n=5(8m)+8\cdot 3^n-3\cdot 3^n = 5(8m)+5\cdot3^n=5(8m+3^n)$

which is clearly divisible by 5 and proves the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $2^{3(n+1)}-3^{n+1} = 8(2^{3n}-3^{n})+3^n(8-3).$

Answer (score 1):

we have $$2^{3n}-3^{n}=8^n-3^n\equiv 3^n-3^n\equiv 0\mod 5$$

Answer (score 0):

By I.H. we have $2^{3n}-3^{n}=5k$ for some integer $k$ and thus $2^{3n}=3^{n}+5k$.

Now we have:

$$2^{3(n+1)}-3^{n+1} = 8\cdot 2^{3n}-3^{n+1}= 8(3^{n}+5k)-3^{n+1} = 3^n(8-3)+40k = 5\cdot (3^n+8k)$$

and we are done.

Comment: Very interesting, I put my solution at least 5 minutes before TheStrangeQuark and his solution is accepted, which is the same as mine,  while my is not even useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to read your handwriting but it looks like you have the right idea but were sloppy in your execution and made so distributive error.

Assume if $n=k$ then statement is true and

$2^{3k} - 3^k = 5P$ for some integer $P$.  (Always a good idea to specify what a variable is whenever you introduce it.)

$2^{3k+1} -3^{k+1}= 2*2^{3k} - 3$.

Theres two errors here:  $2^{3(k+1)} \ne 2^{3k+1}$ and ... why did the $3^{k+1}$ turn into a $3$.

You should have:

$2^{3(k+1)} - 3^{k+1} = 2^{3k + 3} - 3^{k+1} = 8*2^{3k} - 3*3^{k}$

Can you go from there?

$8*2^{3k} - 3*3^{k} = 5*2^{3k} + 3*2^{3k} - 3*3^k = 5*2^{3k} + 3(2^{3k} - 3^k) = 5*2^{3k} + 3(5P) = 5(2^{3k} + 3P)$