# Finding the remainder after division by $3$ is simple. What about the quotient?

Tags: arithmetic

A well-known simple trick for obtaining the REMAINDER after division by 3 is just the digital root of the dividend after division by 3, the digital root itself further simply obtained by first casting out 9's, then every digit pair that add up to 9, etc.

> In the same vein, is there a short-cut method to rapidly obtain the QUOTIENT after division by 3?

Comment: No, you simply have to divide by $3$ to find out the quotient. In very special cases, the quotient can be obvious, but in general, there is no shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if we can call it shortcut,

in base $10,$
Using [Why is $a^n - b^n$ divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b) 
$$\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^n10^ra_r}3=\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{10^r-1}3\cdot a_r+\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^na_r}3$$

$$=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^na_r}3+\sum_{r=0}^n\underbrace{33\cdot33}_{r\text{ digits }}\cdot a_r$$

Comment: In other words, the required quotient which is integer part of N/3 is just (digital sum of N)/3 + weighted digital sum of N by repdigits 333... Right ?

Comment: @BeedassyLekraj, Right you are

Comment: Great ! For instance, 2020 ÷ 3 gives quotient [(2 + 0 + 2 + 0)/3] + (2×333) + (2×3) and remainder (2 + 0 + 2 + 0) mod 3, or (673 × 3) + 1, which is indeed correct !

Comment: In essence, this method simplifies computing the quotient after division by 3 to merely computing the quotient of digital sum of dividend after division by 3, and in general may be further iterated as many steps as may be deemed necessary ! [N/3] = [(digital sum of N)/3] + 3×(weighted sum of digits by appropriate repunits).

Comment: BTW, the weighted sum of digits of dividend by repunits is actually equivalent to the sum of all successive digital truncatations from the right of dividend without the last end digit. For N = 2020, thus [2020/3] = 3×(202 + 20 + 2) + [(2 + 0 + 2 +0)/3] = 3×224 + 1 =673.