# How to prove 1111......11 (91 digits) is a prime or composite number?

Tags: prime-numbers, geometric-series, repunit-numbers

> How to prove $1111......11$ ($91$ digits) is a prime or composite number?

**My Approach:**

$1111......11$ can be expressed as $10^{0}+10^{1}+10^{2}+...…..+10^{90}$

Using summation of a geometric progression formula,

$$10^{0}+10^{1}+10^{2}+...…..+10^{90} = 1\frac{(10^{91}-1)}{(10-1)}=\frac{(10^{91}-1)}{(9)}$$

I do not know how to proceed after this step. Kindly guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Suggest google on "repunits" or "repunit primes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $m=pq$ where $p>1,q>1$ are natural numbers

using [Why is $a^n - b^n$ divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b)

$$\dfrac{a^m-1}{a-1}=\dfrac{a^{pq}-1}{a-1}=\dfrac{(a^p)^q-1}{a-1}$$ will be divisible by $\dfrac{a^p-1}{a-1}$ which will be $>1$ as $p>1$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So the number $111...11$ (n times) is prime if and only if n is prime. Am I right?

Comment: @Intellex, If and only if is not correct. This is only necessary condition, not sufficient

Comment: @Intellex, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit#Decimal_repunit_primes

Comment: Thank you for your answer and link. May be 111 could be an example, where the number of 1's is 3, i.e., prime but is divisible by 3.

Answer (score 5):

Let me illustrate on a smaller repunit:

$111111=11\cdot10101$ and $111111=111\cdot1001$, because $6=3\cdot2$

Yours is the same problem, except $91=7\cdot13$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$91=13(7)$$  so you may factor $$1111111$$ and your number is  $$1111111(10^{12\times {7}} + 10^{11\times 7}+10^{10\times 7}+...1)$$

So it is composite.

Comment: Did you mean $12\times\color{red}7$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks for the comment. I fixed my error.