# Proof of the following statement : $41^a - 14^a$ is a multiple of $27$ for $a \in \Bbb N$

Tags: divisibility

Can anyone give me a simple proof of this statement . I know how to prove it using principle of mathematical induction so please prove it in some other way.

Comment: Well, $x-y$ divides $x^n-y^n$ so $41-14=27$ divides your expression.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, $41^a = (27+14)^a = 27m + 14^a$, for some $m \in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing modulo $27$,
\begin{align*}
 41^a - 14^a &\equiv 14^a - 14^a \\
 &\equiv 0 \pmod{27}
\end{align*}
(since $41 = 27 + 14$) so $27$ divides your number.