# Prove by mathematical induction that for every integer n that is greater than or equal to zero, 5 divides 6n+1 − 1.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-mathematics

Can someone show a step by step process on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Use parentheses, they are important.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b

Comment: That’s clearly false.

Comment: $6n+1-1=6n$ and not all multiples of $6$ are multiplies of $5$. Are you sure you have the question written correctly?

Comment: You really want to proof that $5$ is a divisor of $6$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $5$ divides $6^{n+1}-1$?

Answer (score 2):

If you meant $5$ divides $6^{n+1}-1$, here's an outline for a proof by induction.

Base case:  $n=0$:  $5$ divides $6^1-1=5$.

Inductive step:  Assume $5$ divides $6^{n}-1$.

Then can you see how to show that $5$ divides $6^{n+1}-1=6\times6^n-1=5\times6^n+6^n-1$?

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, the statement is false in the present form (independent of possibly forgotten brackets) and in particular not provable by induction.

$5\not\mid 6\cdot 1 +1-1=6$

$5\not\mid 6(1 +1)-1=11$

$5\not\mid 6\cdot 1 +(1-1)=6$