# How could this be proven?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove that $7 \times (5^2)^n + 12 \times 6^n$ is devisible by $19$ for any $ n$.

I there a way to prove this using mathematical induction?

I will appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Is it true for $n=2$? I don't think so.

Comment: The statement is false as stated. I think OP meant $5^{2n}$ rather than $5^{2}n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mathematical induction.

We can check for $n = 0, 1, 2$.

Now if $\, 7 \times 5^{2n} + 12 \times 6^n$ is divisible by $19$

$\, 7 \times 5^{2(n+1)}+12 \times 6^{(n+1)} = 7 \times 5^{2n} \times 25 + 12 \times 6^n \times 6 = 7 \times 5^{2n} \times (19 + 6) + 12 \times 6^n \times 6$
$= 7 \times 5^{2n} \times 19 + 6 (7 \times 5^{2n} + 12 \times 6^n)$. Then it is divisible by $19$ for $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$7\cdot5^{2n}+12\cdot6^n=7(5^{2n}-6^n)+19\cdot6^n$$

Now use [Why is $a^n - b^n$ divisible by $a-b$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188657/why-is-an-bn-divisible-by-a-b) for   $$5^{2n}-6^n=(5^2)^n-6^n$$