# Help in understanding special algebra expansions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL1bT.jpg)

I cannot understand how this formula is called and in what cases it is applied.  Can you help with this and give examples of equations using these formulas?

Comment: It's a special case of the [Polynomial Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/188661/242).

Answer (score 0):

$$S = 1 + a + ... + a^{n-1}$$
$$aS = a + a^2 + ... + a^{n}$$
So by subtracting $$(a-1)S = a^n - 1$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

So this is basically just geometric progression! You can derive the second result similarly - i.e. divide LHS and RHS by $(a+1)$ and observe that the sum $(1-a+a^2...-a^{2k-1}+a^{2k})$ is a geometric progression with common ratio $=-a$. Doing a manipulation similar to what I did above with $S$ will lead you to the result.

Examples of where these are used? Well, it's always nice to have some factorization tricks up your sleeve.