# Show that $2^n+1\mid 8^n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried by induction but at induction step I struck.I am bad at proving statements which involve variables as exponents.I gladly appreciate any help

Comment: $a+1 \mid a^3+1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [factorization of a^n+1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28572/factorization-of-an1) As usual, some may feel that a less general duplicate target is required.

Comment: Would you like to accept an answer, Mathematical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic:  $2^n\equiv -1 \mod 2^n+1$,

so $8^n=2^{3n}=(2^n)^3\equiv(-1)^3=-1\mod 2^n+1$

Answer (score 4):

$8^n+1=(2^n+1)\left((2^n)^2-2^n+1\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1, 2^n+1= 2+1= 3$ which divides $(8+1)=9$.

So let it be true for $n = k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ . This means $2^k+1 | 8^k+1$.

Now for $n = k+1$ we get,
$$ 8^{k+1} +1 = (4^{k+1})(2^{k+1}+1)-(2^{k+1})(2^{k+1}+1)+(2^{k+1}+1) = (2^{k+1}+1)(4^{k+1}-2^{k+1}+1)$$

which is a multiple of $2^{k+1}+1$.

Hence by the principle of mathematical induction it is proved that $(2^n)+1 $ divides $(8^n)+1$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
This is a proof using induction.

Comment: This induction proof is not good as when you prove $n=k+1$ is correct, you do not use the information of when $n=k$. So, this is not a great induction proof.

Comment: But that information is not necessary to use in this case and I think it is better to do this problem without using induction.

Answer (score 0):

As $8^n=\left(2^3\right)^n=2^{3n}=\left(2^n\right)^3$, let $a=2^n$:
$$n^3+1=(n+1)(n^2-n+1)\\\therefore n+1|n^3+1$$